# State Machine after_transition callback not working on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

I am using `Rails-4.2.6`, state_machine-1.2.0 and `Ruby-2.3`
I had defined state machine on Order model. As follows

```
  state_machine :status, initial: :initiated do
    after_transition on: :succeeded, do: :oderable_success_callback
    event :pending do
      transition initiated: :pending
    end

    event :failed do
      transition [:initiated, :pending] => :failed
    end

    event :succeeded do
      transition [:initiated, :pending] => :succeeded
    end
  end

  def oderable_success_callback
    orderable.successful_payment
  end
```

when I update order like as follows, after_transition callback is triggered.

`order.succeeded`

but it wont trigger callback when I update order as

```
order.update(status: 'succeeded')
```

`status` is updated to '`succeeded`', **but fail to trigger callback.**

How can I trigger `after_transition` callbacks on normal `update`.

Answer (score 1):

**order.update** will not trigger after_transition call back. If you want to  detect changes on column. You can use after_update callback of model.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :tasks
  def tasks
    if(self.status_changed? && status == 'succeeded')
      oderable_success_callback
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Actually I have multiple callbacks depending on status. If I trigger like this then lots of if/else need to write.

Answer (score 1):

I had multiple callbacks depending on status and avoid multiple if/else, I did as follows,

```
 after_update :orderable_callback

 state_machine :status, initial: :initiated do
    event :pending do
      transition initiated: :pending
    end

    event :failed do
      transition [:initiated, :pending] => :failed
    end

    event :succeeded do
      transition [:initiated, :pending] => :succeeded
    end

    state :pending do
      def orderable_callback
        orderable.pending_payment
      end
    end

    state :failed do
      def orderable_callback
        orderable.failed_payment
      end
    end

    state :succeeded do
      def orderable_callback
        orderable.successful_payment
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know you could define per-state methods like that. But what does it do if it's in a state that doesn't have an `orderable_callback` defined? (like the :initiated state) Wouldn't the after_update callback fail then?

Comment: You need to define orderable_callback method outside the state machine which will be called default if not specified in the state machine. For initiated it will call default ```orderable_callback```